# IBM_DB Gem issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, db2, ibm-cloud, devops

When I try to deploy my app to Bluemix I get the following error. My `manifest.yml` file is here as follows.

```
applications:
- path: .
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  domain: mybluemix.net
  name: KnowYourBrand
  host: kyb
  command: bundle exec rake db:setup && bundle exec rails s -p $PORT
  disk_quota: 1024M
  services:
  - Personality Insights-n2
  - Tone Analyzer-uu
  - Insights for Twitter-bt
  - kybSQLDB
  - AlchemyAPI-tw
  buildpack: https://github.com/ibmdb/db2rubybuildpack
```

> 2015-11-17T13:04:51.55-0600 [App/0] ERR LoadError: libdb2.so.1: 
>       cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - 
>       /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ru by/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/
>       2.2.0-static/ibm_db-2.6.1/ibm_db.so

My gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'backbone-on-rails'

gem 'whenever', :require => false

group :production do
  gem 'ibm_db'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '>= 3.1.2', :platform => :ruby

gem 'httparty'

gem 'figaro'
gem "cf-autoconfig", "~> 0.2.1"

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

What could the issue be? I tried setting the `ibm_db` version to an older version, but that did not resolve the issue either.

> Environment variable IBM_DB_HOME is not set. Set it to your
>   DB2/IBM_Data_Server_ Driver installation directory and retry gem
>   install.

What is the best way to handle this without having to install a driver on my local machine? I am just trying to deploy it to Bluemix.

Comment: Are you using the SQLDB service or MySQL service? Your question says mySQLDB but you have IBM DB2 listed elsewhere...

Comment: Also could you please add your manifest.yml file and gemfiles to your question?

Comment: Hi Alex - I have attached the above.  I have tried getting rid of ibm_db gem and the ruby buildpack, and will see how that pans out.

Comment: Hi Alex - I am still seeking a resolution on this issue.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but it appears that you need to set the `IBM_DB_HOME` environment variable. You can [configure environment variables either using the `cf set-env` command, in your `manifest.yml` file](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/deployingapps.html#app_env), or in the Bluemix dashboard. I'm not familiar enough with `ibm_db` gem or DB2 to say what the value should be for this environment variable, but [this README in the gem](https://github.com/ibmdb/ruby-ibmdb/tree/master/IBM_DB_Adapter/ibm_db) may be helpful (search the page for "IBM_DB_HOME").

Answer (score 0):

You can track this question in ibm_db git issue repository [here](https://github.com/ibmdb/ruby-ibmdb/issues/46#issuecomment-162069464)

Answer (score 0):

The ibm_db gem auto downloads the required files while installing the gem. However after ibm_db gem is installed in Bluemix, it is not able to link the downloaded libraries.

**To resolve this problem, please follow below steps.**

**Step-1**. While pushing application with migration, pass a command to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable as below.

> cf push BlogApp2 -c "export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.0/lib/clidriver/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
>   bundle exec rake db:migrate"

**Note** : While running above commad, please specify the Ruby version and ibm_db version that you have specified in gemfile. You can also refer the path in LoadError: libdb2.so error message that you see in server logs on Bluemix.
After application is pushed, you will see that migration has run and you will also see database connection error which is expected.

**Step-2**. Add below Environment Variable in your application. Login to bluemix -> select your Ruby application -> Click on Environment Variables manu -> Select User defined. -> Add below variable -> Save.

**Name** - LD_LIBRARY_PATH

**Value** - /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.0/lib/clidriver/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH    *[Refer step-1 for the value]*

After adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH to your application in Bluemix, you can push your application from cf command as below.
cf push BlogApp2 -c "null"

Now your application will connect to SQLDB.

Thanks,
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this post when I was setting up a Docker image for a node.js server that uses ibm_db. I know this is a ruby app, but this information may help the next person down the road. Here is my Dockerfile that makes node_db available and working.

```
    FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR .

# need to download the ibm drivers and set IBM_DB_HOME
ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
RUN mkdir /ibmdriver
RUN curl https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz \
  | tar -xzf - -C /ibmdriver/
ENV IBM_DB_HOME /ibmdriver/clidriver
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$IBM_DB_HOME/lib



# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available ([email protected]+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

ENV BCCB_DECISIONTREE_SERVICE_PORT 3000

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```